# syntax error : 'type'

Tags: c

```
int max(int N, ...){
    int* x = &N;
    x = x + 1;
    int max = x[1];
    for(int k = 1; k < N ; k += 1){
        if(x[k] > max) {max = x[k];}
    }
    return max;
}

void main(){
    //printf("%d", max(3));

}
```

I've tried compiling the above code from an key solution, but Im getting the error syntax error : 'type' 
What's going on...

Comment: You are treading on thin ice with a variable called 'max' inside a function called 'max'.  The compilers accept it, but 'gcc -Wshadow' warns about the local declaration hiding the global one.  You could not write a recursive max() this way.

Comment: Also, note that standard C requires 'int main(void)' - main returns an integer value, not no value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `x = x + 1` does not do what you expect.

You need to use `stdarg.h` in order to handle variable arguments.

Comment: You might want to amplify on that - something to the effect that the stack normally grows downward, but N is at the top of the list of values pushed onto the stack, so 'x = x + 1' is accessing frame pointers or return addresses or variables in calling functions, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using a C89 compiler.  That code is written for a C99 or C++ compiler - to convert it, you need to move the declarations of `max` and `k` to the top of the function.

Comment: That is the smallest problem with this code, though it is the likely source of his specific error.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <limits.h>

int max(int N, ...)
{
    int big = INT_MIN;
    int i;
    va_list args;

    va_start(args, N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        int x = va_arg(args, int);
        if (big < x)
            big = x;
    }
    va_end(args);
    return(big);
}

#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", max(6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8));
    printf("%d\n", max(5, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8));
    printf("%d\n", max(4, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8));
    printf("%d\n", max(3, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8));
    printf("%d\n", max(2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8));
    printf("%d\n", max(1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8));
    printf("%d\n", max(0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 8));
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiles well in gcc

```
gcc foo.c -std=c99
```

the option to set is as c99 so that for loop counter declared goes well.